# can postgresql scale to the likes of sql server? is it easy to tune?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, postgresql

hoping someone has experience with both sql server and postgresql.

Between the two db's, which one is easier to scale?
Is creating a read only db that mirrors the main db easier/harder than sql server?

Seeing as sql server can get $$, I really want to look into postgresql.

Also, are the db access libraries written well for an asp.net application?

(please no comments on: do you need the scale, worry about scaling later, and don't optimize until you have scaling issues...I just want to learn from a theoretical standpoint thanks!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Currently, setting up a read-only replica is probably easier with SQL Server. There's a lot of work going on to get hot standby and streaming replication part of the next release, though.</strike>

Regarding scaling, people are using PostgreSQL with massive databases. [Skype uses PostgreSQL](https://developer.skype.com/SkypeGarage/DbProjects/SkypePostgresqlWhitepaper), and [Yahoo](http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2008/05/23/PetascaleSQLDBAtYahoo.aspx) has something based on PostgreSQL with several petabyte in it.

Comment: The answer predated PostgreSQL 9.0. With >= 9.0, it is easy to set up replication.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Postgresql with C# and ASP.Net 2.0 and used the db provider from devart:

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/

The visual designer has a few teething difficulties but the connectivity was fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have only used SQL Server and not much PostgreSQL, so I can only answer for SQL Server.

When scaling out SQL Server you have a couple of options. You can use peer to peer replication between  databases, or you can have secondary read-only DB(s) as you mention. The last option is relatively straight-forward to set up using database mirroring or log shipping. Database mirroring also gives you the benefit of automatic switchover on primary DB failure. For an overview, look here:

- http://www.microsoft.com/sql/howtobuy/passive-server-failover-support.mspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917680.aspx
- http://blogs.technet.com/josebda/archive/2009/04/02/sql-server-2008-database-mirroring.aspx

As for licensing, you only need a license for the standby server if it is actively used for serving queries - you do not need one for a pure *standby* server.

If you are serious, you can set up a failover cluster with a SAN for storage, but that is not really a load balancing setup in itself.

Here are some links on the general scale up/out topic:

- http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/wp-sql-2008-performance-scale.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479364.aspx

ASP.NET Libraries are obviously very well written for SQL Server, but I would believe there exists good alternatives for PostgreSQL as well.